# Dropbox Desktop application issus

Tags: android, dropbox

I have an issue with the Dropbox desktop application. When i upload a file (Details.pdf) using the Dropbox SDK from my app to Dropbox. I got (uploaded) the file in the Dropbox web application but i can't find it in Dropbox desktop application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the web-app do you see the file? If not, it has never been uploaded, so the problem is in the app. If you do, the problem is in the syncing process of the desktop version.

Comment: I saw the file.i have sent many times and i have seen the files many times in my dropbox account.when ever i sent the file i seen it within 5 sec in my dropbox account

Comment: So take a look to what's happening in your desktop environment. Internet connection, wrong settings, stuff like this.

Comment: every thing is good.If i upload a file into dropbox from web app normally (not from my app).Then that file is found in my  desktop app also.and same thing happens when i upload a file into desktop then that file is founf in my  web app also.File is not found only when i upload from my app(Android project).Thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't really know, the only thing I could think to is that the file is hidden. If you're on linux, hit Ctrl-H, on Windows on Folder settings, and take a look.
Or, maybe, you're uploading the file telling DropBox it's not to be synced. If you post the code it'll be easier to find out the problem.

Comment: The problem is solved.It is due to some Incompatible characters in the file name (https://www.dropbox.com/help/145/en).Now it is good..Once again thanks for answering.